# Crispr complex in human cells?

Tags: dna, crispr

Is the crispr (where the parts of Virus DNA is saved) section of the DNA existing in human cells aswell or is it just in bacteria cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No analogues of the CRISPR-Cas system have been found in any eukaryotic species, including humans. So far, it appears to have evolved only in prokaryotes and archaea.

Reference: [Evolution of RNA- and DNA-guided antivirus defense systems in prokaryotes and eukaryotes: common ancestry vs convergence](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13062-017-0177-2)